# Add columns to table at runtime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a table mapped by the following xml file:

```
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true" default-access="property"
    default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">

    <class abstract="false" name="domain.CustomFlow"
        table="CUSTOM_FLOW">

        <id column="CUSTOM_FLOW_ID" name="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="customForm"
            class="domain.CustomForm" fetch="select">
            <column name="FORM_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <dynamic-component insert="true" name="customProperties"
            optimistic-lock="true" unique="false" update="true">
        </dynamic-component>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I do update xml mapping at runtime so it will look like:

```
<dynamic-component insert="true" name="customProperties" optimistic-lock="true" unique="false" update="true"><property column="testColumn" generated="never" lazy="false" name="testColumn" not-null="false" optimistic-lock="true" type="java.lang.String" unique="false"/></dynamic-component>
```

How can I update the db schema at runtime. I'm using hibernate and spring?

Answer (score 0):

have look [here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/hibernate-custom-fields) 
it will show you how to update table structure on fly

Comment: I'm already working on this tutorial but this doesn't work with spring.

Comment: but that part is only hibernate side what spring part resist you to do so?